# What machine learning model should be used to predict coincidence factor

Tags: machine-learning

I have coincidence  factor for different sizes of groups and the associated attributes (e.g. building usage type and floor area) for each consumer in the group. I want to predict coincidence  factor for new groups using the attribute for each consumer in the new group and the number of consumers in the group. What machine learning method can solve the problem? :)

*Defintions:*
Coincidence factor is the peak of a system divided by the sum of peak loads of its individual components

Comment: Would you show the regressors?  are regressors somehow correlated to thi incidence factor?

Comment: Yes. The coincidence factor fall with the number of consumers. The coincidence factor also depends on the building types e.g. private home use domestic hot water at the morning creating a spike which not existing for office buildings.

Comment: I should mention that the output should be nummeric (e.g. between 0-1) - not a cateogry/class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are saying I guess you have both categorical and continuous variables, One suggestion would be to check the distributions of your features to see if, more or less, the criteria for a linear regression are met. 
If you have too many variables, which I still haven't picked up, you could even apply a PCA and then a regression.

Comment: What about supervised or unsupervised machine learning (clustering, SMV, ...) can they be used to solve the problem?

Comment: What I just said 'Regression' is supervised learning. You don't need unsupervised as you already have a target variable defined. You could use a dimencionality reduction method(PCA) to ease the regression somehow